# How to politely address an older relative's birthday card

Tags: politeness

I am a 69 year old English speaking Canadian woman. I am about to send a birthday card to a second cousin in Japan. We have never met. This woman is going to turn 100yrs old. How should I address her in the card?
Should I use her family name Mrs.____-san? or her given name ____-san? or Dear cousin?

Comment: To clarify, are you writing to her in English?

Comment: Yes mainly in English

Answer (score 1):

In Japanese, san is equivalent to Mr/Miss/Mrs/Ms, so it’s unnecessary to say Mrs xxx-san. Just use Mrs xxx(family name) or xxx-san (family name) instead. It’s also OK by just saying Dear xxx (first name) if you are familiar with each other.

Comment: Hi Allan, can you clarify for the person asking the question of this is what should be written in English, Japanese, or both?

Comment: Hi I am going to have to write mainly in English but wanted to be sure I was respectful to this relative. Thank you for your help